# How to grab both front and back faces in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I am making a sculpture and i want to manipulate a cylinder to make an arm... Im trying to bend it a certain way but the grab tool wont grab the back faces. Is there a function to enable so i can grab the mesh as a whole and not only the front faces?

Comment: You could increase brush size way higher or zoom out from the model. Brush will affect on the model much stronger and grab everything even not visible from the current point. However I think rough work like grabbing big parts of mesh usually are done in Edit mode.

Comment: It's best to do this in edit mode but Blender can't usually handle that many polygons in edit mode. You might want to switch to some different app for sculpting than Blender. For example Zbrush - there is 90 days unlimited trial.

Comment: Did you check this option in sculpt mode? ![front_faces_only][1] [1]:http://www.pasteall.org/pic/100775

Answer (score 1):

I also wish there was a way to make things easier, because you can’t always use edit mode. You can in fact manipulate back facing vertices if you zoom in inside the model.
[image]

[image]